# getting data from a website Api to a android app

Tags: java, android

I have some Java knowledge but its very fresh. Yesterday I started learning some Java for Android and encountered a problem. Specifically I want to retrieve a decimal number from a website API for some in-app calculations. I have code that works perfectly in normal Java, but when I insert it into Android Studio it compiles but the app crashes at start. Any help would be appreciated.

Here's the number retrieval code :

```
        URL url = new URL("api.example.com");

    URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
    InputStream is =con.getInputStream();

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

    String line = null;
    int cont=0;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        cont++;
        if(cont==28){
            Dol = Double.parseDouble(line.substring(25, 31));

        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you opening the url connection on the main thread?

Comment: @M4rtini yes since its a small learning app, im doing everything there. All tho its in an independent methd

Comment: Androids prevents any networking code to be run in the main thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception

Comment: Don't do network operation on main thread . Use `Asynctask` instead for network operations

Comment: @M4rtini  OHH! thats good to know, thanks guys. so if i implement a new class with that same code it should work?

Comment: @Nilesh thanks man! why is Asynctask better than network operations and sorry for bothering. Thanks!

Comment: see  this link http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html

Comment: [AsynchTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) is a convenience class for doing processing (like networking) in a second thread, and pushing the result back to the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

anything related to networking tasks you need to perform in `AsyncTask` only
try it in `AsyncTask`